# ConfigurationProperties with record and inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, record, java-17

Suppose I have two classes:

```
class Base {
    String from;
    // getters/setters
}
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties("mine")
class Properties extends Base {
   String to;
   // getters/setters
}
```

With such a scenario, I can do :

```
mine.from = 1
mine.to   = 2
```

I'd like to move `Properties` to a `record`, but records do not allow extends, as such the only option I have is to do composition instead of inheritance here:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("mine")
record Properties(String to, Base base) {
}
```

The problem is that now properties need to be changed:

```
mine.base.from = 1
mine.to        = 2
```

Is there a way to tell Spring to use `mine.from` instead of `mine.base.from` for the binding?

Comment: if I think a bit more, this would make no sense if possible. `min.from=1` (if it was possible), but then `mine.getBase().getFrom()`... yeah, I don't think this is sane at all

Comment: What is the actual meaning of this setup? That every instance of `Properties` is supposed to have the specified values?

Comment: @Holger right. basically providing a file with two lines like so :`mine.from=1` and `mine.to=2` (+ some Spring specific annotations), will result in an actual instance of `Properties` created with the specific values from the file.

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense if some other class’s field of type `Properties` had such an annotation to denote that this specific field should be initialized with such an instance? Why should the annotation be of a global nature (being placed at the class) when describing only one instance (and where does that instance live, actually)?

Comment: @Holger its a _single_ instance per application anyway, so it makes sense to be on the class, but that's not the point anyway. imo.

Comment: I’m just trying to wrap my head around the idea that a strictly immutable value-like object is a valid replacement for a mutable bean.

Comment: @Holger I see. The bean can be made immutable though, but I've tried to simplify the example.